# CodeIgniter CLI + HMVC, Echoing Out Index View/Controller instead of cron controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

server is a DV4 from mediatemple running centos. `$DOC_ROOT/index.php - 777 has perms`.

**path to PHP:** `/usr/bin/php`

**path to index.php:** `/var/www/vhosts/example.com/client/fhaz/index.php`

**path to cron.php:** `/var/www/vhosts/example.com/client/fhaz/application/controllers/cron.php`

**When i run the following command:** 
`/usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/example.com/client/fhaz/index.php cron processCategoryCount`

Its running the index controller printing out the compiled view in index(homepage) and not the cron controller/method related to the cron processCategoryCount

Ive also tried: `index.php/cron/processCategoryCount`, `index.php "cron/ProcessCategoryCount`

accessing `index.php/cron/processCategoryCount` in browser properly returns `NOT CLI` which is executed by a construct in the cron controller to `die("NOT CLI");` So i know its accessible..

I ran into this issue before a few months ago, but forgot the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was `$config['uri_protocol']` was set to `QUERY_STRING` and not `AUTO`